# How to detect a network down from a client side with Boost asio ssl socket

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost

I have a websocket using a boost ssl stream. All operations are async. After it connects to the server. I would like to detect network down from the client side, eg. unplug cable, close lid of your laptop or machines go to sleep.

I have enabled keepalive on socket level and set it to 5 secs, which can be proved by using WireShark. When I monitor the dest IP in WireShark, I can see a bunch of dup ack every 5 secs. After there is a valid message received from the server side, they would become normal tcp keep alive messages. Putting machine to sleep then waking up will generate the dup ack loop again.

But my client app never seemd to detect this connect drop. From what I can see, it depends on how long the drop is. When the drop is not long, the client can recover itself. But if I left it over night, the client would still be running next day morning, but it doesn't seem to receive any message from the server any more and no indication about websocket connect is down.

In my client app, I don't write to the server. Only async read from the server.

I would expect when the connection drops or machines go to sleep, the last async read could detect that, so when the network is back, it can reconnect to the server.

Do I miss something? What is the proper way to detect network down from client side?

Comment: Your best bet is to have a secondary timeout.  It's good to always have one in all networking apps, A timeout that resets the socket and reconnects, is the last line of defense against all kind of networking bugs. That would at least generate more debug data to find the issue, The timeout really needs to be there for robustness.

Comment: What do you mean by "A timeout that resets the socket and reconnects"? A timer to periodically check if the socket is valid, if not reconnect?

Comment: Yes. That's what it is, a receive timeout.  You reset the timer when you have input coming in, else reset the connection.

Comment: I think there is a timeout option for the underlying socket for receiving. I will give that a try.

Comment: Using setsockopt to set receive timeout doesn't do anything either. If I setup a timer, how do I check if the connection is valid? Sending a message?

Comment: No.  It has to be a independent timer that you define.  You may also need to add a ping in your protocol.  As a general rule, if you stay connected for long periods, your client is expecting some data.  Timeout on receiving that.  If there is a sendng error, the socket call will fail, So timers on sending are usually not necessary.  If your client is not expecting data, stay disconnected most of the time.